# How do i reinterpter_cast vector to int?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

I've got a vector of four bytes:
`std::vector<int8_t> src = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xa };`, which in hexadecimal is. (0x0000000a)

How do i type-pun it into an `int32_t` so that i get 10 using `reinterpret_cast`?

This can be done easily using bitshifts like this:

`(int32_t)((src[offset] << 24) | (src[offset+ 1] << 16) | (src[offset+ 2] << 8) | (src[offset+ 3]));`

but as far as i'm aware of how `reinterpret_cast` work, it can be used here at its best, but i can't firgure out how exactly do that in code itself.

```
reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&0x0000000a);
```

ps: This is not just for int32_t or so, this can be reinterpreted to anything i would wish. That's the point.

Comment: Depends on your endianness, I would guess. Any reason why the calculation route is considered off-limits?

Comment: @paxdiablo big endian, x64.
I did that in java, which doesn't have Type punning mechanism as far as i know. I was guessing i could have done that in C++ much easier using reinterpret_cast, bub haven't figure that out yet.

Comment: Just a note that you can actually do this is Java using `ByteBuffer` - `ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte [] { 0x0, 0x0, 0x27, 0x10 }).asIntBuffer().get()`

Comment: @greg-449 yeah, i know.  Thing is, i need to "treat" the bytes the way i want using the unsafe method. reinterpret_cast is the way to go in C++, i'm pretty sure. But i can't figure out the exact way of how to do this. I have the stream of bytes, i want to reinterpret them out of vector into the anytype i want.

Comment: Did you tried `int32_t value = *(reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(src.data()));`?

Comment: Why not `*reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&src.at(0))` or an old C-style type pun `*(int32_t*)&src.at(0)`.  (you should not use either -- but they do work - but the result will be endian dependent)

Comment: All `reinterpret_cast` options risk alignment problems, and therefore undefined behavior, in theory.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think the start of a vector is guaranteed to be aligned for any type. (But it's still a strict aliasing violation)

Comment: How do i memcpy instead of reinterpret_cast? Seems like it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible; an attempt would be undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation. An array of `int8_t` cannot be accessed as some other type (except for this specific cases listed in the rule, such as `uint8_t`).

Using bitshifts or memcpy are correct ways (as is the idea of S.M.'s answer)

Comment: I thought the whole point of features like reinterpret_cast is giving the control over any specific situation to the programmer at his/her risks. I know the bits. I just want to reinterpret them the way i want. Vector elements lay down in memory just like int32_t if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Richard the strict aliasing rule still applies regardless of casts .  You could use a compiler extension perhaps (e.g. supply `-fno-strict-aliasing` to gcc)

Comment: i'm on MSVC so we will let it go i guess. Speaking of memcpy. It gives the same result just like reinterpret_cast. So apparently, the only way to type pun this is bitshifting ofr bit-sets(C++20).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int8_t> src = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x27, 0x10 };
  std::cout <<
    std::accumulate(src.begin(), src.end(),  // or src.begin() + sizeof(int32_t)
       0, [](const uint32_t &a, const uint8_t &b){ return a * 256 + b; });
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the int8_t values are negative

Comment: @M.M Thanks. Fixed it.